# Running count records in time series according to a condition

Tags: r, data.table

I have a toy dataset with timestamp and price like this one:

```
time <- c(as.POSIXlt("2017-02-03 09:00:01"),
        as.POSIXlt("2017-02-03 09:00:03"),
        as.POSIXlt("2017-02-03 09:00:06"),
        as.POSIXlt("2017-02-03 09:00:09"),
        as.POSIXlt("2017-02-03 09:00:10"),
       as.POSIXlt("2017-02-03 09:00:20"),
       as.POSIXlt("2017-02-03 09:00:23"),
       as.POSIXlt("2017-02-03 09:00:34"),
       as.POSIXlt("2017-02-03 09:00:44"),
as.POSIXlt("2017-02-03 09:01:07"))

price <- c(100, 100, 100, 99, 98, 99, 100, 101, 101, 100)

data <- data.frame(time, price)
```

I need to loop through the data.frame, find consecutive sequences of records at the same price, count the number of records in these sequences and calculate the duration in seconds from the first to the last member of the same-price-sequence.

So, for the above example the result is:

```
start, end, price, nbr_records, duration_sec
2017-02-03 09:00:01, 2017-02-03 09:00:03, 100, 3, 5
2017-02-03 09:00:09, 2017-02-03 09:00:09, 99, 1, 0
2017-02-03 09:00:10, 2017-02-03 09:00:10, 98, 1, 0
2017-02-03 09:00:20, 2017-02-03 09:00:20, 99, 1, 0
2017-02-03 09:00:23, 2017-02-03 09:00:23, 100, 1, 0
2017-02-03 09:00:34, 2017-02-03 09:00:44, 101, 2, 10
2017-02-03 09:01:07, 2017-02-03 09:01:07, 100, 1, 0
```

Preferably a fast data.table solution as I have a lot of records.
Thanks!

Comment: Sure: 3 subsequent records at 100, one at 99, one at 98, again one at 99, one at 100, two at 101 and one at 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I deleted my comment, I understand what you're going for after a second read-through.*

This is pretty straightforward using `rleid()` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

## Note: store times as POSIXct instead of POSIXlt for drastic performance improvement
time <- c(as.POSIXct("2017-02-03 09:00:01"),
          as.POSIXct("2017-02-03 09:00:03"),
          as.POSIXct("2017-02-03 09:00:06"),
          as.POSIXct("2017-02-03 09:00:09"),
          as.POSIXct("2017-02-03 09:00:10"),
          as.POSIXct("2017-02-03 09:00:20"),
          as.POSIXct("2017-02-03 09:00:23"),
          as.POSIXct("2017-02-03 09:00:34"),
          as.POSIXct("2017-02-03 09:00:44"),
          as.POSIXct("2017-02-03 09:01:07"))

price <- c(100, 100, 100, 99, 98, 99, 100, 101, 101, 100)

data <- data.frame(time, price)

## Convert to a data.table
setDT(data)

## Create a summary using a generated counter on the fly with 
## the `rleid` function from data.table to group consecutive
## sequences together and then operate by group. the `.N`
## operator is another special symbol in data.table
## that we can use to return the number of rows in each group
## here. See ?special-symbols to learn more
Summary <- data[, .(start = first(time),
                    end = last(time),
                    nbr_records = .N,
                    duration_sec = as.numeric(last(time)) - as.numeric(first(time))
                    ), by = .(Counter = data.table::rleid(price))]

## Drop the Counter variable assuming you don't need it
Summary[,Counter := NULL]

## Results
print(Summary)

#                  start                 end nbr_records duration_sec
# 1: 2017-02-03 09:00:01 2017-02-03 09:00:06           3            5
# 2: 2017-02-03 09:00:09 2017-02-03 09:00:09           1            0
# 3: 2017-02-03 09:00:10 2017-02-03 09:00:10           1            0
# 4: 2017-02-03 09:00:20 2017-02-03 09:00:20           1            0
# 5: 2017-02-03 09:00:23 2017-02-03 09:00:23           1            0
# 6: 2017-02-03 09:00:34 2017-02-03 09:00:44           2           10
# 7: 2017-02-03 09:01:07 2017-02-03 09:01:07           1            0
```

Comment: Yep, exactly that! Thanks! Tried with 600K records - really quick!

Comment: @user1766682, please, consider to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark. This will indicate that the question has an accepted answer. Thank you.